# Кэшироваие в tomcat8

Tags: tomcat, кэширование

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как включить кеширование файлов для `tomcat 8`? 
Столкнулся с тем что сайт долго грузится - сжал `css`, `js`. Стало легче, но гугл советует включить кеширование браузера. Как это сделать на `tomcat 8` я не знаю.

Спасибо.

**Что пишет Google:**

Используйте кеш браузера

Если указывать в заголовках HTTP дату или срок действия статических ресурсов, браузер будет загружать уже полученные ранее ресурсы с локального диска, а не из Интернета.

И идёт список файлов.

**Ответ:**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=86400
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Thu, 20 Apr 2017 09:29:02 GMT
ETag:W/"27653-1492672656000"
Expires:Fri, 21 Apr 2017 09:29:02 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 20 Apr 2017 07:17:36 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос фразу которую говорит вам гугл. и добавьте где он вам это говорит.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил в топ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную функцию можно добавить используя фильтры. Вас интересует [Expires Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter). Эта конфигурация включит кеширование для всего на один месяц.

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresDefault</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 1 month</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: я добавил это в web.xml самого tomcat-а. Но как увидеть результат?

Comment: в Chrome Dev Tools или в Firebug посмотрите заголовки ответов. там будут  **Expires** и **Cache-Control: max-age**

Comment: увидел. но почему-то у меня Expires стоить на день. Пример ответа скинул в шапку.

Comment: вы перегружали сервер? какую страницу вы проверяли?

Comment: Да, перезагружал. Главную.

Comment: добавьте в **logging.properties** строчку **org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.level = FINE** и перегрузите сервер. перегрузите страницу и потом ищите в **catalina.out**  **ExpiresFilter**

Comment: как-то так:
**FINE: Filter initialized with configuration ExpiresFilter[excludedResponseStatusCode=[304], default=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[1 MONTH]], byType={text/css=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[1 DAY]], application/javascript=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[1 DAY]], image=ExpiresConfiguration[startingPoint=ACCESS_TIME, duration=[1 DAY]]}]**

Comment: @Tsyklop главную станицу чего вы проверяли? Сервера или приложения? Проверьте, что у вас не прописаны другие фильтры.

Comment: Приложения. Зашел на страницу самого приложения.

Спасибо.